# How can I perform weighted addition of three layers in keras?

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I would like to perform the weighted addition of three outputs from different Keras layers such that the weights are trainable. How can I achieve this? I am using tensorflow 2.0 as backend for Keras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem using subclassing in keras. The code is shown below:

```
class Wt_Add(keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, units=1, input_dim=1):
    super(Wt_Add, self).__init__()
    w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
    self.w1 = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units), dtype="float32"),
        trainable=True,
    )
    self.w2 = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units), dtype="float32"),
        trainable=True,
    )  
    self.w3 = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim, units), dtype="float32"),
        trainable=True,
    )       

def call(self, input1, input2, input3):
    return tf.multiply(input1,self.w1) + tf.multiply(input2, self.w2) + tf.multiply(input3, self.w3)
```

Usage:

```
wt_add = Wt_Add(1,1)
sum_layer = wt_add(input1, input2, input3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following basic operations on layers:

- `tf.keras.layers.Lambda` so you can multiply each of your 3 layers with a simple lambda operation

```py
layer1 =  tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * weight1)(layer1)
layer2 =  tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * weight2)(layer2)
layer3 =  tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * weight3)(layer3)
```

then there is the `tf.keras.layers.Average` that allows to average layers:

```py
average_layer = tf.keras.layers.Average()([layer1, layer2, layer3])
```

It's a bit awkward, I think a weighted average would be the best thing here but it does not seem to be available in Keras yet (as far as I know)

Comment: Thanks. However on saving the model, following error is displayed: 

"Tried to export a function which references untracked object Tensor("36550:0", shape=(), dtype=resource).TensorFlow objects (e.g. tf.Variable) captured by functions must be tracked by assigning them to an attribute of a tracked object or assigned to an attribute of the main object directly."

Comment: In addition, following warning is displayed during training: "The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (lambda_10), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer."

Comment: looks great - thanks I'll take note of this

Comment: Do you need to constrain the three learned weights so they sum to 1? Like using a dirichlet?